# Correct way to reference "count" column in a sort statement

Tags: mysql

What's the correct way to reference the `count(*)` column in the sort statement of the following query?

```
select a.*, count(*) as 'Count'
from table_a a
join table_b b
    on a.id = b.id
where b.status = 1
order by ??
```

`order by count(*)` works however is MySQL then going to count all of the records twice?  That seems inefficient.

`order by 2` doesn't work because it is factoring all of the columns in table_a.

I could do `order by 8` for example however it will break and need updating if the number of columns in table_a ever changes.

Comment: In mysql, you can use alias defined in the select clause in order by statement

Comment: It should see `count(*)` as repeated and not calculate it twice.

Answer (score 3):

Use alias name in order by

```
select a.*, count(*) as C
from table_a a join table_b b
on a.id = b.id
where b.status = 1
order by C
```